# do I add <mobile> tags in a jquery mobile sitemap or not?

Tags: jquery-mobile, sitemap

I'm doing a sitemap for a site done in jquery mobile. I'm targeting both desktop and mobile, so...

Do I add entries with the **mobile** tag like this:

```
<url><!--  some -->
   <loc>http://someurl.com</loc>
   <lastmod>2012-01-01</lastmod>
   <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
   <priority>0.25</priority>
   <!-- use this or not?-->
   <mobile:mobile/>
</url>
```

or without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what Google states, it seems you may have to have 2 sitemaps.

If you use the mobile tag it is for mobile only content, therefore it won't index it for desktop.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34648

From the link above: "A Mobile Sitemap can contain only URLs that serve mobile web content. Any URLs that serve only non-mobile web content will be ignored by the Google crawling mechanisms. If you have non-mobile content, create a separate Sitemap for those URLs."

Comment: hm. so much for "one-source-fits-all". Thanks though!

Comment: Well your source for your website/application is technically the same. It's having to create multiple sitemaps for webmaster tools that the issue is. I do agree that this is annoying and redundant in your case though.